# What causes C++ compiler error: must have argument of class or enumerated type?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Function declaration:

```
template <typename T>
Point<T>* operator +(Point<T> const * const point, Vector<T> const * const vector);
```

It's been a while since I've used C++ so maybe I'm doing something really stupid.  Let me know.

Also, no, I am not using namespace std.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're doing wrong here on the language level is overloading operators for pointers. At least one argument of an overloaded operator must be of a user-defined type, or a reference to one.

But you're also doing this wrong on another level. You're returning a pointer, which means you will probably need to allocate some storage dynamically in the operator. Well, who owns that storage? Who will release it?

You should just take references and return by value, something like:

```
template <typename T>
Point<T> operator +(Point<T> const& point, Vector<T> const& vector) {
    return Point<T>(point.x + vector.x, point.y + vector.y);
}
```

Comment: One of the reasons I'm returning a pointer is I couldn't figure out how to return by value.  Where would I get this Point<T> from?  I can't make a new() one and return it like this.

Comment: @Doug: I added an example, considering typical Point and Vector classes. If you come from Java, the first thing you need to learn is that `new` is to be used very frequently.

Comment: What sort of allocation does this have?  Is it somehow scoped with the calling function?

Comment: @Doug: it is local to this function (it's called *automatic storage*, in constrast to *dynamic storage*), but it will be copied to the return value (the compiler is allowed and will most likely optimize the copy away, so don't worry about the copies slowing you down). It will also be cleaned up on its own. And I'm sorry, above about `new` I meant "**not** to be used frequently."

Comment: Yeah I was concerned that automatic storage would go out of scope and get deallocated, but it seems this is a way to avoid the deallocation because it's copied to the return value.  Or actually, it would get deallocated and it would be inefficiently making a copy, but the compiler will likely optimize that away, making this efficient again (not constructing the value twice hopefully).

Comment: @DougTreadwell even if the compiler doesn't avoid the copy, note that for small objects like the usual Point and Vector things, dynamic allocation is likely slower than copying a couple of floats or doubles.

Comment: Is this a sort of optimization I should rely on or is it better in general to return pointers to newly allocated things in factory functions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: I hope you meant: is that new is **NOT** used very frequently.

Comment: @Tux-D: yeah, that's right. I only noticed when it was already too late :( but I tried to fix the damage in a later comment :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't overload operators for fundamental types, in your case both arguments are pointers. Did you want references instead?

Comment: So even if it's a pointer TO some particular type, I still can't overload it?

Comment: @DougTreadwell It would be hard to have pointer that doesn't point to a particular type wouldn't it? ;)

Comment: I meant, points to a user defined type.  But I suppose the compiler doesn't look at what it points to, just what it is?

Answer (score 4):

When you define an operator, at least one of the arguments must be a user-defined class or enumerated type (or a reference to one of those). Pointers don't qualify as either of those. You should be using reference arguments, and returning an unqualified Point<T>.

Comment: How would I return an unqualified Point<T>?