# interesting issue operator overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)
>   [What causes C++ compiler error: must have argument of class or enumerated type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493932/what-causes-c-compiler-error-must-have-argument-of-class-or-enumerated-type)

I am trying to play a little bit with operator overloading and genericity in C++ and I seem to have 3 little errors when I try to compile. Have a class named Grandeur with template D, and then I inherit 3 classes from this one, named `Temps(time)`, `Longueur(size)`, `Vitesse(speed)`, and I am trying to overload the operators such as when I do `Temps+Temps->Temps, Vitesse+Vitesse=Vitesse,Longueur+Longueur->Longueur, Longueur/Time->Vitess` etc.
In order not to write 3 times the same functions for the operations of same type, I use templates to utilise the genericity. But I have an error when I try to compile. Here is my code:

```
typedef double Longueur;
typedef double Temps;
typedef double Vitesse;



template<typename D>
class Grandeur {
  protected :
    double val; const char* unite;



  public :
    Grandeur(double qqc) : val(qqc) {}
    Grandeur(int qqc) : val(qqc) {}
    Grandeur(long qqc) : val(qqc) {}
    Grandeur(float qqc) : val(qqc) {}

    inline friend D operator+ (const D a, const D b) {
      return D (a.val + b.val);
    }

    inline friend D operator- (const D a, const D b) {
      return D (a.val - b.val);
    }

    inline friend double operator* (const D a, const D b) {
      return a.val * b.val;
    }

    inline friend double operator/ (const D a, const D b) {
      return a.val / b.val;
    }

    inline friend D operator* (D a, const int b) {
      return D (a.val * b);
    }

    inline friend D operator/ (const D a, const int b) {
      return D (a.val / b);
    }

    inline friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, D d) {
      return os << d.val << d.u;
    }

    class Temps : public Grandeur<Temps> {
    public:


  };

  class Vitesse : public Grandeur<Vitesse> {
    public:


  };

  class Longueur : public Grandeur<Longueur> {
    public:

  };

};




inline Longueur operator* (const Vitesse v, const Temps t) {
  return Longueur(v.val * t.val);
}

inline Vitesse operator/ (const Longueur l, const Temps t) {
  return Vitesse(l.val / t.val);
}

inline Temps operator/ (const Longueur l, const Vitesse v) {
  return Temps(l.val / v.val);
}
```

When I try to compile it says:

> `g++ essai.cc`
>      `In file included from essai.cc:4:0:`
>       `grandeurs.h:70:58: error: ‘Longueur operator*(Vitesse, Temps)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type`
>       `grandeurs.h:74:58: error: ‘Vitesse operator/(Longueur, Temps)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type`
>       `grandeurs.h:78:58: error: ‘Temps operator/(Longueur, Vitesse)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type`

The lines 70, 74 and 78 are those with the last 3 functions (the inlines). What can I do?

Comment: The classes you use as parameter types don't exist in that scope.

Comment: ok ,I understand now. But since I use genericity I cannot write it explicitly. What could I do?

Comment: I do not know how to change that.

Comment: Simply move `class Vitesse : public Grandeur<Vitesse> { ... }` and `class Longueur : public Grandeur<Longueur> { ... }` out of `template<typename D> class Grandeur { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the operators at global scope so the types `Vitesse` etc are not available to the compiler. Why not move the child classes outside `Grandeur<T>`'s definition?

EDIT for comment:
You're trying to use the operators with double values, but the implicit conversions are *not* automatically inherited by your child classes. You'll need to define them in each child and pass the parameters up to the parent template class.

Comment: if i do that i get: grandeurs.h:35:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘Longueur::Longueur(double)’
grandeurs.h:35:26: note: candidates are:
grandeurs.h:57:9: note: Longueur::Longueur()
grandeurs.h:57:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
grandeurs.h:57:9: note: Longueur::Longueur(const Longueur&)
grandeurs.h:57:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘double’ to ‘const Longueur&’