# Prefix vs infix operator* with string literals

Tags: c++, string, c++11, operators

I recently gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321702/2970186) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166630/how-to-repeat-a-string-a-variable-number-of-times-in-c) on how to get Python-like string repeats, e.g. `"hello" * 2` gives `"hellohello"`.

I won't repeat the definition here, but the function declaration is:

```
std::string repeat(std::string str, const std::size_t n);
```

and can of course can be used like:

```
std::cout << repeat("helloworld", 2) << std::endl;
```

To get closer to the Python version, I thought I'd overload `operator*`. Ideally I'd use a universal reference to avoid the additional `std::string` move, but [operators must use a user-defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493932/what-causes-c-compiler-error-must-have-argument-of-class-or-enumerated-type). So I tried this instead:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if_t, std::is_integral
#include <utility>     // std::move

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
std::string operator*(std::string str, const T n)
{
    return repeat(std::move(str), static_cast<std::size_t>(n));
}
```

Now I can do this:

```
std::cout << (std::string("helloworld") * 2) << std::end;
```

and this:

```
std::cout << operator*("helloworld", 2) << std::endl;
```

but not this:

```
std::cout << ("helloworld" * 2) << std::endl;
// error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char *' and 'int')
```

Why not?

Comment: If you have c++14, try `("helloworld"s * 2)`.

Comment: FWIW, I asked something [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591262/why-doesnt-stdstring-define-multiplication-or-literals) a good while back. Granted it's two questions in one and one of those is actually in C++14.

Comment: @aschepler I think marking this as duplicate is a little harsh. I hadn't seen that question, but I think this question is different in that I'm asking why the prefix version of operator works vs the infix version. Which the other question doesn't highlight.

Comment: @Daniel: Marking a question as a duplicate isn't a condemnation of the new question; it's merely an attempt to ensure that there aren't multiple discussions of the same issue all over the site. Also, even though my question doesn't explicitly highlight prefix vs. infix, the reasoning is exactly the same.

Comment: @R_Kapp It wasn't at all obvious to me there was any difference between prefix vs infix (I thought infix was simply syntactic sugar), and reading the answer to your question doesn't answer that either. Perhaps I'll edit the question to emphasis this.

Comment: I've just come across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352640/infix-vs-prefix-syntax-name-lookup-differences) question which addresses prefix vs infix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define an overloaded operator, at least one of the operands must be of a user-defined type. For pre-defined types, all operators are either pre-defined, or else prohibited.

Where you've explicitly converted to `std::string` the `string` ctor that takes a `char const *` as its parameter can/will be used to convert the literal to an `std::string`, but without that, the compiler can't/won't do the conversion.

Likewise, when you invoke the operator more explicitly as `operator*("helloworld", 2)`, the compiler "knows" that it needs to convert the string literal to a type supported by an overload of `operator *`, so it (basically) enumerates all the types to which a string literal can be converted, and then sees if it can find an `operator *` that fits one of those types. If it finds more than one, it does (if memory serves) normal overload resolution on the candidate `operator *` implementations to decide which to use.

With just the expression `string-literal * int`, however, both types are built in, so it only examines the built-in operators. Since none of them fits, the expression is prohibited.

Note that with a current compiler, you could use a suffix of `s` on the string literal to create a `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

std::cout << "helloworld"s * s << "\n";
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused why `operator*("helloworld", 2)` works, but `"helloworld" * 2` doesn't. I haven't explicitly converted the string literal into a `std::string`, and isn't the latter converted by the compiler into the former (i.e. aren't prefix and postfix `operator` equivalent)?

Comment: @Daniel: I've added a little more explanation that I hope clarifies the situation a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Because `"helloworld"` is not a `std::string`, it's a `char` array.

Comment: No it's not, it's a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). And this doesn't explain why the prefix version works.

Comment: @Daniel From your link: "The ___type___ of an unprefixed string literal is `const char[]`".

Comment: Can I reclaim some pride by noting you missed a `const`? :p